# Как в консоль вивести букву " і " и изменить ціет текста на например #001200

Tags: c#

Собственно суть в названии. Пробивал менять кодировку консоли на стандартную для windows 1251(если загружать файл при помощи File.ReadAllText то при етой кодировки загружается буква " і "), но вместо
" і " получилось " | ". С цветом совсем не понимаю как...
Использую .NET Framework 4.0, Windows 8.1 Профессиональный.

Comment: `стандартную для windows 1251` стандартная для Windows кодировка начиная с Windows 7 - UTF-8, а для консоли при русских региональных настройках стандартная кодировка - CodePage 866.

Comment: Нужно было разбить вопрос на два: один по присвоению цвета, другой - по кодировке.

Comment: `" і "` - суть проблемы в том, что это [Unicode Decimal Code &#1110](https://www.codetable.net/decimal/1110) - кириллическая буква, а не латинская. Об этом тоже следовало написать.

Comment: Отредактируйте вопрос, добавив в него всю необходимую информацию, в том числе версию Винды и какой фреймворк используете: .NET FW или .NET Core (и его точную версию).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov ну я сразу смекнул это, получив `?` в консоли в CP866

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov отредактировал вопрос

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov `суть проблемы в том, что это Unicode Decimal Code &#1110 - кириллическая буква, а не латинская. Об этом тоже следовало написать.` - А что тут непонятного, разве невидно что кириллица?